# Extracting the first few characters of a filename without substring? Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working with files that contain their filedate in the filename.

***202209021021_example pandas.csv***

How do i extract the first 6 characters without using substrings?

Kind regards,

Ayoub

Comment: Any specific reason behind this request of not using substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LEFT function in case if you are leveraging dataflows
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#left

Comment: @Ayoubhle glad it helped out but any reason why not use substring?
because you can use a normal expression tab for it rather than leveraging dataflow. Just a thought!!!!